# Cannot find the file ~/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/connections.xml in my mac

Tags: mysql-workbench

Need the connections file of mysql workbench but haven't been able to find it in my mac.

Tried the path /Library/Application Support but there is no MySQL folder.
Also the path /usr/local/mysql-8.0.33-macos13-arm64 but I have no idea where the connections.xml file is.
Even with a search in the finder it doesn't seem to exist in my computer.
Where does the MySQL workbench created connections go?

Answer (score 0):

I found it as follows:
Go to your mac's volume; then go to Users (not directly to Library); select your user, in there: Shift + Command + . (it shows the hidden files), go to library , application support and you will find the MySQL folder.